# Video(with Audio) chat for iOS

Tags: ios

I"m trying to build an app for iOS which includes video(with audio/voice) and text chat. The chat will be one-on-one chat. One source for video is surely coming from desktop/laptop camera(or IP Camera). How can this be achieved for iOS devices?  Any open source/ free library as solution available will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these 
1)  http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS

2) https://layer.com/

3) http://www.pubnub.com/

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Our web platform uses Flash component for video calling. How could I connect Quickblox API with that to have a video chat from iOS device, so that one client on desktop uses flah component and other on iOS/Android device

Answer (score 0):

`ooVoo` provides free sdk for video chat implementations its very easy to use. But for free sdk it will have `ooVoo` logo at the bottom of the screen. For more information go to this link:  https://developer.oovoo.com/

If you want to implement your own video chat application. You can use xmpp, this link has a good example for xmpp implementation on iOS :https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework [it doesn't have video chat implementation you have to modify it].

Or you can write your own custom socket program. In which you will be able to send and receive `UDP` packet which will contain the video data.